# Downcast generic class

Tags: swift, inheritance

I've got a generic class based on some type, and a child class which specifies that type. However, the Swift compiler doesn't seem to be able to downcast the parent class with the correct type to the child class.
I'm surprised because it seems like a legitimate need.

For example

```swift
class MyClass<T> {}

class ChildClass: MyClass<Double> {}

func test() {
  let instance = MyClass<Double>()
  let castedInstance: ChildClass = instance as! ChildClass
}
```

This code throws a runtime error: `Could not cast value of type 'MyClass<Swift.Double>' (0x1f3e449f0) to 'ChildClass' (0x1024f58b0).`

Is there any way to cast it the right way, or is it forbidden for some reason ? Anything I misunderstood ?

Comment: You can't cast to something that is not true; `instance` is _not_ a ChildClass so the cast fails. Do not lie to the compiler about what something is.

Comment: What is this “from a”? Can you please add an actual use case? I can’t tell what you’re asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have a misunderstanding of how inheritance works. You cannot convert the type of an object using type casting, whether that's up- or down casting.

You can only use downcasting when the object you are trying to cast is declared/stored as a more general type (a parent class for instance), but it might hold a more specialised instance (subclass). However, you are declaring a parent instance and then trying to downcast it to a subclass. That can never work, since the instance is of a different type.

Your example works if you declare a variable of the parent class type, but assign a child class instance to it.

```
func test() {
  let instance: MyClass<Double> = ChildClass()
  let castedInstance: ChildClass = instance as! ChildClass
}
```

Comment: I was indeed confused with how you can force cast types in `C++` asking the compiler to reinterpret the data in memory. Thanks for making that clear, I've edited my question

Comment: @BigBro your update to the question doesn't really make sense. Why would you want to create a subclass instance from a parent class instance? Please provide a real use case, since with the current overly simplified example, this seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). And probably best to ask a separate question with the real world example, since it seems to be different from the original question, which might still be useful for future readers in its current form.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear but I found the solution to what I was looking for. I'll remove my edit for future readers and approve your answer. My usage was to convert a `Matrix<N, P>` to a `Vector`, which is a `Matrix<N, One>` whenever a dot product created one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you misunderstand what casting is. Casting *reveals* to the compiler what something actually is. It does not *change* what that thing is.

So you cannot cast `instance` to ChildClass, for the simple reason that it is *not* in fact a ChildClass.

Comment: Makes sense :) I've edited my question accordingly